# For which constant will all nontrivial solutions be oscillatory?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been given the following problem:

For which $a\in\mathbb{R}$ will all nontrivial sol'ns of the eq $x''+ax'+4x=0$ be oscillatory about zero?

The characteristic exponents are

${r_{1,2}}^{*} = \frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-16}}{2}$

and my book says that these sol'ns are oscillatory whenever $\Im(r^*)\neq0$.

How does this follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the variables

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{{\rm d}x}{{\rm d}t} &=& y \\
\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}t} &=& \frac{{\rm d}^2x}{{\rm d}t^2} = -a\frac{{\rm d}x}{{\rm d}t} - 4x = -ay - 4x \tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}

In matrix form this is

$$
\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ -4 & -a 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \tag{2}
$$

or equivalently

$$
\frac{{\rm d}{\bf z}}{{\rm d}t} = A {\bf z} \tag{3}
$$

The solution to this problem is

$$
{\bf z}(t) = e^{A t}{\bf z}_0 \tag{4}
$$

So the problem is reduced to finding $e^{At}$, it $A$ is diagonalizable, then $A = U \Lambda U^{-1}$, where $\Lambda$ is diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $A$, remember that to find those we need to solve ${\rm det}(A - \lambda I) = 0$, which in this case is

$$
0 = {\rm det}\begin{pmatrix} - \lambda & 1 \\ -4 & -a -\lambda\end{pmatrix} = \lambda(a + \lambda) + 4 ~~~\Rightarrow~~~ \lambda_{\pm} = \frac{-a \pm \sqrt{a^2 - 16}}{2} \tag{5}
$$

(looks familiar?) Once you have this values, you just need to calculate the exponential $e^{A t}$, but that is easy since

\begin{eqnarray}
e^{At} &=& \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(At)^k}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{t^k}{k!}A^k \\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^k}{k!} (U\Lambda U^{-1})^k  
= \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^k}{k!} U\Lambda^k U^{-1}  \\
&=& U\left(\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^k}{k!} \Lambda^k \right)U^{-1}  
= U\left(\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^k}{k!} \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1^k & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_-^k \end{pmatrix}\right)U^{-1}  \\
&=& U \begin{pmatrix} \sum_k t^k\lambda_1^k/k! & 0 \\ 0 & \sum_kt^k\lambda_-^k/k! \end{pmatrix} U^{-1} \\
&=& U \begin{pmatrix} e^{\lambda_+ t} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{\lambda_- t} \end{pmatrix} U^{-1} \tag{6}
\end{eqnarray}

If you replace that into Eqn (4) you get the behavior of $x(t)$. What's important to realize here is that if $\lambda_{\pm}$ is complex, say $\lambda_{\pm} = -a/2 \pm i \omega_{\pm}$, then

$$
e^{\lambda_{\pm} t} = e^{(-a/2 \pm i \omega)t} = e^{-a/2}[\cos{\omega t} \pm i \sin(\omega t)]
$$

which leads to an oscillatory solution!

Comment: Could you use (6) to determine other aspects of the solution's behaviour (e.g. boundedness, etc)? How exactly would you use (6) to determine the solution's behaviour?

Comment: @blargen Remember that ${\bf z}(t) = e^{A t} {\bf z}_0 = {x(t) \choose x'(t)} $, so you need to expand the matrix product and will get both $x(t)$ and $x'(t)$